# Find a curve that intersects the line $y = 2$ at an infinite number of points

Tags: limits, continuity

[Curve problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmuvY.jpg)

Find a curve that intersects the horizontal asymptote $y=2$ at a infinite number of points.

This is from CALC 1 limits by the way.

What I know already:

- I know that to have a horizontal asymptote you must have the numerator and the denominator be of the same degree. So to have a horizontal asymptote I would need something like $2x/x$.
- I also know that to intersect a line at infinite number of points, I would need something like a $\cos$ or a $\sin$ function. However, I can't seem to get a $\cos$ or $\sin$ function that has a horizontal asymptote at $y=2$.

Comment: Oh. I totally forgot about transformations!

Answer (score 3):

$$y = 2 + {\sin (x) \over x}$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about the basic transformations.